# Angular2 http.post form value to php server

Tags: php, http, post, angular

I'm trying to send form values from Ionic2(Angular2 typescript) project to a php server in which I will send contact mail.

I can't get the values I'm supposed to...

Here is my form.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable}               from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response}           from 'angular2/http';
import {Headers, RequestOptions}  from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}               from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class FormService {
  constructor (private _http: Http) {}

  private _contactUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/Server/email.php';
  // private _contactUrl = '/email';

  sendMail(value: Object): Observable<any> {
    const body = JSON.stringify(value);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body, {
      headers : headers
    }).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Which is used from my onSubmit function in my form.ts:

```
import { Page, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,  ControlGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from 'angular2/common';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FormService} from './form.service';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/form/form.html',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [FormService]
})

export class Form {

  contactForm: ControlGroup;
  company: AbstractControl;
  name: AbstractControl;
  prenom: AbstractControl;
  phone: AbstractControl;
  email: AbstractControl;
  website: AbstractControl;
  message: AbstractControl;

  arrivee: AbstractControl;
  projet: AbstractControl;

  projets = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Site Internet' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Site Intranet/Extranet' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Développement PHP' },
    { id: 4, label: 'Développement C#' },
    { id: 5, label: 'Conception Base de Données' },
    { id: 6, label: 'Tiers Maintenance Applicative' },
    { id: 7, label: "Recrutement d'un collaborateur Handicapé" }
  ];
  arrivees = [
    { id: 1, label: 'Internet' },
    { id: 2, label: 'Recommandation' },
    { id: 3, label: 'Evênement' }
  ];

  response: string;
  value: any;

  constructor(public nav: NavController, fb: FormBuilder, private _http: Http, private _formService: FormService) {
        this.nav = nav;

        // New controlGroup instance
        this.contactForm = fb.group({
          // Validators Rules for each field
          // Champ XXX: ['', ...] correspondants au [ngFormControl]="XXX" de la vue HTML (inpput)
          name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), this.checkFirstCharacterValidator])],
          prenom: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(3), this.checkFirstCharacterValidator])],
          company: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), this.checkFirstCharacterValidator])],
          projet: ['', Validators.required],
          arrivee: ['', Validators.required],
          phone: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)])],
          email: ['', Validators.required],
          website: ['', Validators.minLength(3)],
          message: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20)])]
        });

    this.name =     this.contactForm.controls['name'];
    this.prenom =   this.contactForm.controls['prenom'];
    this.company =  this.contactForm.controls['company'];
    this.projet =   this.contactForm.controls['projet'];
    this.arrivee =  this.contactForm.controls['arrivee'],
    this.phone =    this.contactForm.controls['phone'],
    this.email =    this.contactForm.controls['email'],
    this.website =  this.contactForm.controls['website'],
    this.message =  this.contactForm.controls['message']
  }

// Check if firt character is a number
  checkFirstCharacterValidator(control: Control): { [s: string]: boolean } {
      if (control.value.match(/^\d/)) {
          return { checkFirstCharacterValidator: true };
      }
  }

  onSubmit(value) {
    this._formService.sendMail({value})
      .subscribe(
        response => this.response = response,
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
}
```

And in my email.php file I'm trying to get the POST:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
    }

$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// for test     
echo $value->name;

?>
```

I checked in chrome's console, I'm getting something:
[Screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NejW8.png)

How can I get the post from angular2 into my php? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see two problems in your code:

- You create a JSON content with JSON.stringify but for forms, you need to use the `URLSearchParams` class or create the string content by hand.
- You content type value isn't correct. It's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not `application/x-www-urlencoded`.

Here is what you should use instead:

```
sendMail(value: Object): Observable<any> {
  const body = new URLSearchParams();
  Object.keys(value).forEach(key => {
    body.set(key, value[key]);
  }

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type',
     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body.toString(), {
    headers : headers
  }).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Which properties am I supposed to add in the URLSearchParams? Do the content-type is 'application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'? Merci!

Comment: Regarding the properties, I suppose of the ones from your `value` object... What do you want to send to the server: JSON content or form? I also updated my answer...

Comment: I'm building a contact form, so yes it's a form.

Comment: Do you import both `Headers` and `URLSearchParams` classes from the `angular2/http` module?

Comment: Could you provide what you have within the dev tools in the network tab? To see what is actually sent... Will be helpful to debug your problem

Comment: Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0wjqun4vlg291t/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%202016-05-09%20%C3%A0%2015.32.04.png?dl=0 and the object is here!

Comment: Do you use `body.toString()` in `http.post`?

Comment: yes: return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body.toString(), (...)

Comment: Could you show the source for form data in your previous screenshot?

Comment: Sure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2hsrnortj5mkde/email.php?dl=0 it's a simple php file. I'm trying to get the object...

Comment: and in devtools in the devtools. At the bottom in "Form data" area (by clicking on "view source"... Thanks!

Comment: The Object is empty?

Comment: In fact no but I would see something like in the Form Data area: `param1=val1&param2=val2`. Here is a plunkr describing such processing: https://plnkr.co/edit/jnvBiLA4RGTfo3JZI1pl?p=preview. Don't worry about the 415 error for the request, the important thing is the request content ;-)

Comment: `value=[object Object]` let me think that you use something like that: var body = new URLSearchParams(); body.set('value', value.value);` and the value attribute of your `value` object is an object (not a primitive type) so the class tries to get its string representation (`toString`) which is `[object Object]` by default. Perhaps you could try to set by hand all the properties of your form in the `body` variable...

Comment: Still can't get something...I set the body values and it's the same...If you have time can you get a look : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zxxswqhf34gqbph/AABBKdK3EHBfJXk3RxTCt-Pua?dl=0 thanks this drives me nuts....

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get it working, it was only:

```
  sendMail(value: any): Observable<any> {
    const body = new URLSearchParams(value);
    body.set('name', value.name);
    body.set('company', value.company);
    body.set('projet', value.projet);
    body.set('arrivee', value.arrivee);
    body.set('phone', value.phone);
    body.set('email', value.email);
    body.set('website', value.website);
    body.set('message', value.message);
    body.set('name', value.name);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this._http.post(this._contactUrl, body.toString(), {
      headers : headers
    }).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

And in the form.php:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

$formData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    foreach ($formData as $key=>$value) {
        $_POST[$key]=$value;
    }

$formObject = $_POST['name'];
(...) ?>
```

Thanks to Thierry Templier for his precious help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for someone it will be useful. I had a problem with nested objects - with passing to PHP objects like this:

```
var obj = {
        value: 1,
        innerObj: {
            title: "title",
            innerObject: {
                value: 1
            }
        }
    };
```

I resolved it by using **[querystring parser](https://github.com/tj/node-querystring)**

Example of using:

```
//at top of you .ts file
let qs = require('qs');

return this.http.post(url, qs.stringify(data), {headers: this.postHeader})
    .map((resp: Response) => resp.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error) || 'Server error');
```

It is also will be useful for not nested objects